# SSRS expression: How to put a line break after a special character for an address that is in a table column

Tags: vba, reporting-services, expression

I have a table in SSRS that has multiple addresses, they are all difficult to read and I was wondering if there was a way a line break could be added.

All the addresses start with a 2) or 3) or 1) so a closed bracket would be the marker where  the line breaks should occur, removing the ).

Current format;
5)Passenger Lifts - Insurance - The High St 5-16- due - 28 Jan 22, 5)Passenger Lifts - Insurance - 6 Lovedale Road Flats- due - 09 Sep 21, 5)Passenger Lifts - Insurance - Queens Court 1 - 31 BLOCK- due - 14 Jan 22

Required format;

```
Passenger Lifts - Insurance - The High St 5-16- due - 28 Jan 22,
Passenger Lifts - Insurance - 6 Lovedale Road Flats- due - 09 Sep 21,
Passenger Lifts - Insurance - Queens Court 1 - 31 BLOCK- due - 14 Jan 22
```

Any tips and tricks appreciated

Comment: Have you tried any code? Have you tried Regular Expressions, like Regex.Replace?

Comment: Hi, have you seen my answer below, that suits any "number of values"?

Comment: I just edited to things looks more DRY and SOLID, ie, maintainable and reusable. I you think that it is useful, please upvote the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test it in VBA, but it functions in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eskIV7/1) and is something like this through Regex Replace:

EDIT on 02/04/2022: I managed to get a VBA editor, and put things more DRY and SOLID...

```
Public Sub TestReplaceThroughRegex()
  Dim strOutput As String
  strOutput = _
    ReplaceThroughRegex( _
        "5)Passenger Lifts - Insurance - The High St 5-16- due - 28 Jan 22, 5)Passenger Lifts - Insurance - 6 Lovedale Road Flats- due - 09 Sep 21, 5)Passenger Lifts - Insurance - Queens Court 1 - 31 BLOCK- due - 14 Jan 22" _
        , "\d{1}\)" _
        , "\r" _
    )
    Debug.Print (strOutput)
End Sub

Public Function ReplaceThroughRegex(ByVal strInput As String, ByVal pattern As String, ByVal replacement As String) As String
Static regEx As Object 'VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    'Static declaration means we don't have to create
    'and compile the RegExp object every single time
    'the function is called.

  If strInput = "" Then
    'This is the signal to dispose of oRE
    Set regEx = Nothing
    Exit Function 'with default value
  End If
   
  'Create the RegExp object if necessary
  If regEx Is Nothing Then
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")
  End If
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .Multiline = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .pattern = pattern
    End With
    ReplaceThroughRegex = regEx.Replace(strInput, replacement)
End Function
```

PS: I'm assuming that you will have only 1 digit before ).
If more than one is possible, change for `"\d{1,2}\)"` or `"\d{1,3}\)"`, whatever suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If there's only three possible values and you wanted to use SSRS expressions you could use the Replace function to replace "5)" with vbcrlf which would insert a new line.

```
=REPLACE(Fields!LongString.Value, "5)", vbcrlf)
```

Comment: Hi @SDC Thanks there could be any number of values.

Comment: Used nested replaces and it has worked thanks